# How do I replace part of text inside an element with children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="test">Orange <span class="is">is</span> my favorite color.</div>
```

I only want to replace `Orange` (and the space after it). Using `.text()` won't work because it selects the whole strong.

How do I do this?

Comment: Wrap `"Orange"` in a `<span>` if you want to change it, that'd make things more easy.

Comment: why can't you wrap it with a `span` ?

Comment: I can't change the HTML, this is for a user script.

Comment: `.text().replace(/^\S*\s/, "foo")`

Comment: Try `.childNodes[0]`. Code snippet coming up!

Comment: This has been asked numerous times. Question shows complete lack of research effort

Comment: `$('.test').html('new word ' + $('.test').html().substring($('.test').html().indexOf('<span')));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is harder to do with jQuery than with the native DOM, so if you're using jQuery, you're going to have to convert the element to the native DOM using jQuery's array indexing.

Basically, what we need to do is change the first text node. jQuery isn't really good with text nodes, which is why we use the DOM here:

```js
//This gets the div.test element using jQuery:
var testDiv = $("div.test");
function changeColor(color) {
    /* The following function changes the value of the first text node within testDiv: */
    //This converts testDiv from a jQuery element to a regular DOM element. This is because jQuery isn't really meant to be handling stuff like text nodes, so doing this with the regular DOM will just be much easier.
    var domElement = testDiv[0];
    //Now, just change the value of the first text node:
    domElement.childNodes[0].nodeValue = color;
}

//Now, as you can see if you click div.test, we can replace the color mentioned in div.test using changeColor():
testDiv.click(function() {
    changeColor("Blue ");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Orange <span class="is">is</span> my favorite color.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use native DOM methods. In your case the simples thing is just change `nodeValue` property of the first childNode element (which you know is going to be TextNode element):

```js
var el = $('.test');
el[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = 'Green ';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Orange <span class="is">is</span> my favorite color.</div>
```

or if you want you can grab text node with jQuery's [$.fn.contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method:

```js
var el = $('.test');
el.contents()[0].nodeValue = 'Green ';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Orange <span class="is">is</span> my favorite color.</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you choose `.nodeValue` over `.data`? http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-FF21A306 (Also in DOM2)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery, here is the solution

```
    $('.test').html(function(){
        return $(this).html().replace('Orange ','');
    });
```

Find the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/xff6dw1t/

Used `data attribute` to refine the code and to use it for multiple strings

HTML:

```
 <div class="test" data-replace="Orange ">Orange <span class="is">is</span> my favorite color.</div>
 <div class="test" data-replace="Green ">Green <span class="is">is</span> my next favorite color.</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
    $('.test').html(function(){
        return $(this).html().replace($(this).data('replace'),'');
    });
```

Comment: what if the color is green? Will you write a switch case? :\

Comment: This solves the issue in this particular case, but it isn't a general solution.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution only for your issue. However, If you use data attribute `data-replace="your_text"`, you can use this code for multiple elements. [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/xff6dw1t/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Black";
```